# Any possible step when MATLAB is unable to find explicit solution?

Tags: matlab, function, solver

I am trying to solve a problem using MATLAB, where I have 9 unknowns and 8 equations, and my goal is to write the value of the `F` as a function of `x2: F=f(x2)`, so then I could give different values to `x2` and obtain `F`. The implemented code is:

```
%-------- Variables description -------
%3 constants: P, h and c
%9 unknowns: F, x1,...,x8

syms F P h c x1 x2 x3 x4 x5 x6 x7 x8

%--------System of 8 Equations---------
Eq1 = F == P/(x1*x2/x3);
Eq2 = x1 == x3 - h;
Eq3 = x4 == x2 - x1;
Eq4 = x5 == sqrt(x4^2+(h-c)^2);
Eq5 = x6 == sqrt(x3^2+(x1+x4)^2);
Eq6 = x6 == 3*x5;
Eq7 = x7 == atan((h-c)/x4);
Eq8 = x8 == atan(x3/(x1+x4));

%----------------Solver----------------
Solution = solve([Eq1, Eq2, Eq3, Eq4, Eq5, Eq6, Eq7, Eq8],...
[F P c h x1 x3 x4 x5 x6 x7 x8]);

%----- Solution desired: F=f(x2) ------
Solution.F
```

Nevertheless, the output of this code was:

> "Unable to find an explicit solution.".

I am not sure why I had this problem. Is it possible to get a solution?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The following code solves it for me. You can than generate different solutions variying `x2` in Eq9. Your problem is that you hand `P, c, h` to the solver. Thus it does not treat them as given constants.

```
syms F P h c x1 x2 x3 x4 x5 x6 x7 x8

%--------System of 8 Equations---------
Eq1 = F == P/(x1*x2/x3);
Eq2 = x1 == x3 - h;
Eq3 = x4 == x2 - x1;
Eq4 = x5 == sqrt(x4^2+(h-c)^2);
Eq5 = x6 == sqrt(x3^2+(x1+x4)^2);
Eq6 = x6 == 3*x5;
Eq7 = x7 == atan((h-c)/x4);
Eq8 = x8 == atan(x3/(x1+x4));
Eq9 = x2 == 5;

%----------------Solver----------------
Solution = solve([Eq1, Eq2, Eq3, Eq4, Eq5, Eq6, Eq7, Eq8, Eq9],...
[F x1 x2 x3 x4 x5 x6 x7 x8]);

%----- Solution desired: F=f(x2) ------
Solution.F
```

Besides you can use `fsolve` as numerical solver for equations that are nonlinear

Link to the Documentation [Matlab Documentation for FSolve](https://de.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/fsolve.html)

Comment: I think is a problem with a solution since it is based only on simple physical/trigonometric conditions.

With the second option (IgnoreAnalyticConstraints), the output is an answer with 3 parameterized symbols (z, z1 and z2) which I believe it doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: Thank you very much ohlr! That was exactly the problem. I was giving them to the solver as variables and they are not. Spot on!!
I really appreciate your time and help to solve this issue that took me so much time..